# CiviMail draft takes a really long time to save

Tags: drupal, civimail, caching

We recently upgraded to Debian 9 so I think there are some server configs and tuning yet to be done. Originally draft mailings wouldn't save at all and I recreated the smart group that fed the recipients. I turned off the smart group caching job and created a smart group cache flushing job and changed the caching from opportunistic to deterministic, according to this article: https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/478-group-contact-cache-deadlocks-improvement

It's the autosave function which I believe is also loading the 62,000+ recipients. Once they load, clicking "save" goes much faster. However, opening the draft and making an edit takes a long time to save again.

I checked the MySQL process that is running and there are two at play:

```
| 140355 | db_user | localhost | civicrm | Query   |  540 | Sending data | INSERT INTO civicrm_mailing_recipients (mailing_id, contact_id, email_id)
SELECT 953, i.contact_id,  |    0.000 |
| 140388 | db_user | localhost | civicrm | Query   |  540 | updating     | DELETE FROM civicrm_mailing_recipients WHERE  mailing_id = 946
```

I have cleared the templates_c and flushed caches. Let me know if I can provide any more clues or information. I'm worried about a database corruption. Nothing is being reported in the CiviCRM log for this transaction.

At the time of writing, the draft has been "saving" for about 20 minutes now.

Edit: After the save was complete, there was an error and backtrace in the CiviCRM ConfigAndLog log, which I am unsure if is related, so I'm editing the draft to see if the same error comes up which seems to be related to a specific user. The backtrace suggests it's related to a diffent issue I'm having when users get an unknown DB_Error after using a contribution form. I'm putting it here in case it's somehow related.

```
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_email (contact_id , location_type_id , email , is_primary , is_billing , on_hold ) VALUES ( 139092 ,  1 , 'user@example.org' ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 )  [nativecode=1205 ** Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
```

CiviCRM 5.7.2 on Drupal 7.62.

Comment: And just to confirm - this is only happening with smart groups? Have you tried with a smart group with only a few contacts in it? Does the smart group in question have parent/children smart groups?